# Best way to implement an appointment feature in my Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Using Rails 4, I'm developing an app for fitness enthusiasts and personal trainers. I'm new to Rails, but decided to jump-start my learning by building this app. I read several related posts, but nothing quite on point.  A brief overview of the app ....

After registration, fitness buffs (members) will track training exercises and optionally make appointments with personal trainers.  Personal trainers will create training plans for members.  Not all members will have a personal trainer, however, some members may have many trainers through appointments.  It's important that trainers can not be double-booked for appointments.

So far, I have the following models and associations:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :cardio_exercises, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :strength_exercises, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :trainers, through: :appointments, :dependent => :destroy

class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base  

has_many :cardio_exercises, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :strength_exercises, :dependent => :destroy    
has_many :appointments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :members, through: :appointments, :dependent => :destroy

class CardioExercise < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :member
belongs_to :trainer

class StrengthExercise < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :member
belongs_to :trainer

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :member
belongs_to :trainer

validates :appointment_date, :member, :trainer, presence: true
validates :appointment_date, :trainer, uniqueness: true
```

The appointment_date column in the Appointments table is of the "datetime" datatype. I'm using Rspec to test my application, but struggling to write an effective test to evaluate the appointment feature, particularly I'm grappling with the issue of double-booked appointments. I thought about adding two additional columns to the Appointment Model:  Start_time and End_time, but haven't done so, because I'm not sure if that's the best way to go.

I have several questions:

1. Do my models and associations make sense?  Is there anything I could improve on with the models and/or associations?
2. Is there a "better way" to implement the appointment feature?  Should I include "start" and "end" time columns?
3. How should I go about developing an Rspec test to ensure appointments can't be overbooked?
4. What kind of validation(s) make sense for my appointment model?  As you see, I included a uniqueness validator for "appointment_date" and "trainer."  However, the validation is too restrictive.  It prevents different trainers from scheduling appointments at the same date & time, which is not what I want to do. Obviously, I need something else, but I don't know how best to proceed with the valiations.

Any ideas or suggestions about my models, associations, validations, or test protocol are greatly appreciated!

Comment: To help with #4 look at the scope option for validates uniqueness. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness
You could use something like `validates :trainer, uniqueness: {scope: :appointment_date}

Comment: Coenwulf - thanks for the tip.  Scoping the validation helps!

Comment: Can you divide your appointment times into slots (e.g., half hour increments)? If not I would say you should use start and end times for your appointments. Or start time and duration if that makes more sense.

Comment: I can divide appointment times into slots of half hour increments. That wouldn't be a problem. Start and end times would work too. Your earlier suggestion re validation appears to do a good job of preventing duplicate booking, but I still need to write an automated test to be sure it's working as expected.  If I go with start & end time columns, should I delete the existing datetime column?

Comment: Sorry, I was overlooking your description of the structure and misinterpreted it based on field names. I would rename appointment_date to appointment_at and use a duration. As far as specing it with RSpec you should save one then initialize another one that overlaps it and `expect(overlapping_appointment.valide).to be false`. Then you may need fancier logic for preventing overlaps, but at least you have a starting point.

Comment: Also, CardioExercise and StrengthExercise seem a bit redundant. Maybe make a class Exercise. If there are business logic differences then you could subclass it for those differences. If there are no data structure differences but there are logic differences check out using STI.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer re RSpec, that's what I was thinking about doing! First, I'll create a valid appointment and then create another one with an overlapping date/time.  The only reason I separated Cardio & strength exercises is because the attributes are different (for example, strength exercises have weights, reps, sets, but cardio focuses on time),